# How to connect Oracle DB hosted in Cloud with MS Azure Logic apps

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-logic-apps, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We have a requirement to connect Oracle database hosted in cloud with MS Azure logic apps.

I have done a bit of research on this, I found that we can connect the oracle db on premise data center using the oracle connector present in logic apps but not the oracle db hosted in cloud.

I also found out that we can use Fast Connect + Express Route method to connect to OCI and MS Azure, which might not be feasible in our case.

So, Apart from above solutions, can anyone please point out to any alternatives to connect the oracle db in Cloud to MS Azure logic apps.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What "Cloud"? Oracle Cloud? Where is that Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cross-cloud connection between Oracle Cloud Infrastructure and Microsoft Azure in certain regions. More info can be found here - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/azure.htm?Highlight=connect%20oracle%20database%20to%20azure